# Ruby iterate over an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the below array of hashes.
I want to add a new key,value pair to "hashes" which are in "all" array. Is there any better way of looping through, than what I am doing currently?

```
stack = {
  "all": [
    "mango",
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "grapes"
  ],
  "mango": {
    "TYPE": "test",
    "MAX_SIZE": 50,
    "REGION": "us-east-1"
  },
  "apple": {
    "TYPE": "dev",
    "MAX_SIZE": 55,
    "REGION": "us-east-1"
  },
  "banana": {
    "TYPE": "test",
    "MAX_SIZE": 60,
    "REGION": "us-east-1"
  },
  "grapes": {
    "TYPE": "dev",
    "MAX_SIZE": 80,
    "REGION": "us-east-1"
  },
  "types": [
    "dev",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

My code:

```
  stack['all'].each do |fruit|
   stack[fruit].each do |fruit_name|
     stack[fruit_name]['COUNT'] = stack[fruit_name]['MAX_SIZE'] * 2
   end
  end
```

Expected output:

```
stack = {
  "all": [
    "mango",
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "grapes"
  ],
  "mango": {
    "TYPE": "test",
    "MAX_SIZE": 50,
    "REGION": "us-east-1",
    "COUNT" : 100
  },
  "apple": {
    "TYPE": "dev",
    "MAX_SIZE": 55,
    "REGION": "us-east-1",
    "COUNT" : 110
  },
  "banana": {
    "TYPE": "test",
    "MAX_SIZE": 60,
    "REGION": "us-east-1",
    "COUNT" : 120
  },
  "grapes": {
    "TYPE": "dev",
    "MAX_SIZE": 80,
    "REGION": "us-east-1",
    "COUNT" : 160
  },
  "types": [
    "dev",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you test your code? It contains several errors now. Some of them are more like typos (like trying to access symbol keys using string values) but the internal iteration is logically broken. `stack[fruit]` (or rather `stack[fruit.to_sym)`) is a hash, so iterating over it using `each` will yield NOT `fruit_name` but something _very_ different :)

Comment: I'm guessing you are new to Ruby. Ruby does **not** use `:` to specify key/value-pairs. `:` is used in combination with a valid identifier to create a symbol. If you want to specify key/value-pairs use `=>`. eg. `"TYPE" => "test"` using `"TYPE": "test"` is a shorthand for `:"TYPE" => "test"` or even shorter `:TYPE => "test"` where `:TYPE` is a symbol, not a string. See: [Ruby literals - Hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes)

Comment: I am newbie to rubie and trying to learn. How can I iterate , if not through `each`

Comment: If `stack[:all]` includes `"mango"`, as it does in the example, does `stack` necessarily have a key `:mango`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the second loop. The following does what you want:

```
keys = stack[:all].map(&:to_sym)
keys.each do |key|
  stack[key][:COUNT] = stack[key][:MAX_SIZE] * 2
end
```

In the above code-block `stack[:all]` will return an array of keys as strings, `.map(&:to_sym)` will convert each string in the resulting array into a symbol.

---

Another way to achieve the same result would be to use either [`fetch_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch_values) or [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to retrieve an array of values belonging to the provided keys. The difference being that `fetch_values` raises an exception if a key is missing while `values_at` returns `nil` for that key.

```
fruits = stack.fetch_values(*stack[:all].map(&:to_sym))
fruits.each do |fruit|
  fruit[:COUNT] = fruit[:MAX_SIZE] * 2
end
```

If you are wondering why there is a `*` before `stack[:all].map(&:to_sym)`, this is to convert the array into individual arguments. In this context `*` is called the [spat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion).

Comment: Thankyou, but I cannot change  `stacks[all]` to symbols or any other data. I need to work with the existing data as mentioned in the question

Comment: Jill, that would be a concern had 3... written `stack[:all].map!(&:to_sym)`, but `stack[:all].map(&:to_sym)` creates a new array without modifying `stack[:all]`. 3..., that's gotta be Ruby's nastiest operator.

Comment: why are converting the keys `to_sym` ? In my data, there are not symbols, the value inside keys/fruits are only symbols. Also `all` is not a symbol

Comment: Jill, suppose you define a hash `{ "a":1, "b c":2, "d"=>3 } #=> {:a=>1, :"b c"=>2, "d"=>3}`.  For key-value pairs that are defined with the colon form, the key is *always treated as a symbol*. `b c` must be put in quotes because of the presence of the space. The quotes around `a` are redundant. One would normally write `{ a:1, "b c":2, "d"=>3 }`.

Answer (score 1):

You might write the code as follows.

```
stack[:all].each do |k|
  h = stack[k.to_sym]
  h[:COUNT] = 2*h[:MAX_SIZE] unless h.nil?
end
```

When, for example, `k = "mango",

```
h #=> h={:TYPE=>"test", :MAX_SIZE=>50, :REGION=>"us-east-1", :COUNT=>100}
```

I've defined the local variable `h` for three reasons:

- it simplifies the code by avoiding multiple references to `stack[k.to_sym]`
- when debugging it may may be helpful to be able to examine `h`
- it makes the code more readable

Note that `h` merely holds an existing hash; it does not create a copy of that hash, so it has a neglibile effect on memory requirements.

The technique of defining local variables to hold objects that are parts of other objects is especially useful for more complex objects. Suppose, for example, we had the hash

```
 hash = {
   cat: { sound: "purr", lives: 9 },
   dog: { sound: "woof", toys: ["ball", "rope"] }
 }
```

Now suppose we wish to add a dog toy

```
new_toy = "frisbee"
```

if it is not already present in the array

```
hash[:dog][:toys]
```

We could write

```
hash[:dog][:toys] << new_toy unless hash[:dog][:toys].include?(new_toy)
  #=> ["ball", "rope", "frisbee"] 
hash
  #=> {:cat=>{:sound=>"purr", :lives=>9},
  #    :dog=>{:sound=>"woof", :toys=>["ball", "rope", "frisbee"]}}
```

Alternatively, we could write

```
dog_hash = hash[:dog]
  #=> {:sound=>"woof", :toys=>["ball", "rope"]} 
dog_toys_arr = dog_hash[:toys]
  #=> ["ball", "rope"] 
dog_toys_arr << new_toy unless dog_toys_arr.include?(new_toy)  
  #=> ["ball", "rope", "frisbee"] 
hash
  #=> {:cat=>{:sound=>"purr", :lives=>9},
  #    :dog=>{:sound=>"woof", :toys=>["ball", "rope", "frisbee"]}}
```

Not only does the latter snippet display intermediate results, it probably is a wash with the first snippet in terms of execution speed and storage requirements and arguably is more readable. It also cuts down on careless mistakes such as

```
hash[:dog][:toys] << new_toy unless hash[:dog][:toy].include?(new_toy)
```

---

If one element of `stack[:all]` were, for example, `"pineapple"`, `stack[:pineapple] #=> nil` since `stack` has no key `:pineapple`. If, however, `stack` contained the key-value pair

```
nil=>{ sound: "woof", toys: ["ball", "rope"] }
```

that would become problem. Far-fetched? Maybe, but it is perhaps good practice--in part for readability--to avoid the assumption that `h[k] #=> nil` means `h` has no key `k`; instead, use `if h.key?(k)`. For example:

```
stack[:all].each do |k|
  key = k.to_sym
  if stack.key?(key)
    h = stack[key]
    h[:COUNT] = 2*h[:MAX_SIZE]
  end
end
```